# Работа с массивом php

Tags: php, массивы

Не смог правильно оформить заголовок вопроса, опишу подробно задачу в описании ниже.

Есть выборка с базы данных в виде многомерного массива и записываю его в свойство:

```
array(4) {
  [0]=>
  array(2) {
    ["id"]=>
    int(1)
    ["value"]=>
    string(7) "default"
  }
  [1]=>
  array(2) {
    ["id"]=>
    int(2)
    ["value"]=>
    string(3) "min"
  }
  [2]=>
    array(2) {
    ["id"]=>
    int(3)
    ["value"]=>
    string(6) "online"
  }
  [3]=>
  array(2) {
    ["id"]=>
    int(4)
    ["value"]=>
    string(7) "offline"
  }
}
```

Для получения значения с поля value я обращаюсь к номеру элемента массива и потом к полю value, например:

```
$this->constant[0]['value']
```

Вопрос:

Как обработать данный массив чтоб обращаться к одному массиву через ID и получать его value? На выходе хочу получать значения в таком виде.

```
$this->constant[1] и на вывод должен получить строку `default`
```

Прошу помощи в реализации.

Comment: `foreach ($array as $item) { if ($item['id'] === 666) $value = $item['value']; }`

Comment: Или через `array_filter` с таким же примерно условием

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$this->constant = array_combine(array_column($this->constant, 'id'), array_column($this->constant, 'value'))
```

и после обращаешься

```
$this->constant[id]
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$newarray = array();
foreach($this->constant as $item){
    $newarray[$item['id']] = $item['value'];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$id = 111;
$neededValue = '';

foreach ($array as $item) { 
    if ($item['id'] === $id) {
        $neededValue = $item['value'];
        break; 
    }
}
```

---

```
$id = 111;
$neededValue = array_filter($array, function($item) use ($id) {
    return $item['id'] === $id;
})['value'];
```

Comment: Не совсем понимаю что за данные вне функции?

Comment: @verstala $id - тот id, по которому ищется значение. neededValue - искомое значение из поля `value`